# Keeping checkbox state consistent over multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

I need to check or uncheck automatically two hidden checkboxes when a main visible one is checked.
The three checkboxes are inside a while cycle.

Let me explain myself, this is my form:

```
<form action="updateAuc.php" method="POST" name="edit">
    <div class="editbutton">
         <ul>
             <li class="leditcnt"><input class="submitbutton" type="submit" name="edit" value="Aggiorna Trasferimenti" /></li>
             <li class="lremove"><a href="auctionfree_list.php"><input name="Button"  type="button" class="linkbutton" value="Annulla" /></a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>                
    <table width = "100%">
        <tr class="title">
            <td class="head">Player</td>
            <td class="head">Action</td>
            <td class="head">Win</td>
         </tr>                     

        <?php do { ?>    
        <tr>
            <td class="table1"><?php echo $row_dataauc['playerName']; ?></td>
            <td class="table1"><?php echo $row_dataauc['amount']; ?> - <?php echo $row_dataauc['teambid']; ?></td>
            <td class="table1">
                <input name="enable[]" class="inputfield" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_dataauc['aucid']?>"/>
                <input name="enable2[]" class="inputfield" style="display:none" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_dataauc['id']?>"/>
                <input name="enable3[]" class="inputfield" style="display:none" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_dataauc['coachID']?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_dataauc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataauc)); ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

name=”enable[]” is the main one; when I check this one, name=”enable2[]” and name”enable3[]”must automatically be checked, too.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq. The usual question: "What have you tried?". We're here to help with programming questions, not to write code for you. I suggest you edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, i think your checkboxes should have same name like `enable[]`

onclick function for visible checkbox;

```
onclick="setcb(this)"
```

javascript;

first of all, i think your checkboxes should have same name like enable[]

```
function setcb(element) {
  var status = element.checked ? true : false;
  var elements = document.getElementById("enable");

  for( i=0; i<elements.length ; i++ ) {
    elements[i].checked = status;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using jQuery, but like rcpayan says, it's kind of wonky to have different names.

```
$('input[name=enable\\[\\]]').click(function() {
    $('input[name=enable2\\[\\]]').click();
    $('input[name=enable3\\[\\]]').click();
});
```